# Java 5 automatically expiring cache

Tags: java, caching

I am looking for a caching framework that supports expiring values a specified time after the last access. It must support Java 5.

I looked at the (very-nice) Google Guava library that supports `CacheBuilder`, and they promise a back port to Java 5, but at the present time, it only supports 6 (in the latest build).

I know that writing a performant, thread-safe cache is a difficult task that I would rather not take on.

Comment: For God's sake, upgrade to 6. 5 has been EOL forever now. Virtually no-one has a valid use case for not upgrading.

Comment: while updating (put/remove) do a CAS and expire the cache. While getting, check the timestampt and retry if you have to. It's quite simple 20-30 lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) is a pretty widely used java caching framework.  the elements have an expiry config based on "time to idle".

Comment: I use ehcache and I am happy with it. +1 for good suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Guava is open source.  You should be able to backport the `CacheBuilder` class to Java 5.